# Reverse engineering Newton's approximation of impact depth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, kinetic-theory

I recently learned about Newton's approximation of impact depth, Depth = (Projectile Density / Target Density) * Length of the projectile. Where length and depth is measured in meters, and density is grams per cubic cm. This equation assumes that the projectile is moving faster than the speed of sound (in air I believe) relative to the target. 
This is all fine and dandy for basic calculations.
What if the object is moving 3 times the speed of sound? My intuition says the impact depth would be 3 times as well. But I would rather get confirmation on my assumption.

Comment: no, it is independent of the projectile velocity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth

Comment: But Newtons are calculated by the mass and velocity of an object. It wouldn't make sense to me if an object moving at 686 m/s would make the same impact as an object of equal mass moving at 343 m/s.

Comment: it is explained in teh wikipedia article, if there is any part that you do not understand feel free to ask

Comment: I'm looking for an equation to calculate the depth of penetration when a projectile collides with a target. I don't need to calculate projectile deformation, just the depth based on; velocity, density, surface area of impact, thickness of target, angle of attack, or whatever would be relevant. I am no expert on physics and I would love a better understanding of this part of the subject.

Comment: the equation you want depends on teh approximation and assumptions you make. The Newton approximation is good for large speeds, but for  more accurate predictions I do not know as I am not an expert, sorry